# Magento URL Rewrite Management linking Pages to Nav Bar

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I am trying to link a CMS page to the navigation bar however under url rewrite management I keep receiving " Request Path for Specified Store Already exists. This is what I've done...

1) created the page Portfolio under CMS -> Pages.
Title Portfolio : URL Key portfolio

2) created subcategory Portfolio: Active YES : Include in Navigation Menu YES : URL Key portfolio1

3)Go to URL Rewrite Information and place the following in
and receive the message "Request Path for Specified Store Already Exits:

[image]

Please help - I have already tried  http://jc-designs.net/blog/2012/09/magento-adding-cms-pages-to-the-main-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

This means your system has already created a url rewrite for this category.

For simple fix, you can follow these steps manually:

1. Go to `Catalog > Url Redirects` and search the exact same as you have in your request path
2. Then edit that and
3. Change the target path as you wish.

**If you are only trying to show cms page in that category then there is another better approach**

1. Create a new static block
2. Add your all `cms page` content in there and save
   NOW,
3. Open that category and go to `Display and Settings` section
4. Then change "Display mode" to "static block only".
5. Then in "CMS Block" section choose your cms block and save

This should do the trick.

Comment: Did it help? Can you response please.